# Re-use ElasticSearch filters to test object in memory

Tags: java, lucene, elasticsearch

I'm looking for a way to re-use the filter syntax and logic in ElasticSearch / Lucene on arbitrary documents (without the need to index them first) in Java.

Let's say I have a JSON object

```
{"wheels":4}
```

And the filter:

```
{"exists":{"field":"windows"}}
```

The object is not in any index, is it possible to reuse the ElasticSearch / Lucene filters to test the document on the filter without (or before) inserting it to the index (in this case returning false)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, the feature is called the Percolator in Elasticsearch:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-percolate.html

You register a search in Elasticsearch using the percolate api and then you percolate a document thru it. It returns where or not there was a match. The example syntax below is taken from the documentation - it should give you a good idea of how to get this going:

> **Sample usage**
>
> Create an index with a mapping for the field message:
>
> ```
> curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/my-index' -d '{
>   "mappings": {
>     "my-type": {
>       "properties": {
>         "message": {
>           "type": "string"
>         }
>       }
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Register a query in the percolator:
>
> ```
> curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/my-index/.percolator/1' -d '{
>     "query" : {
>         "match" : {
>             "message" : "bonsai tree"
>         }
>     }
> }'
> ```
>
> Match a document to the registered percolator queries:
>
> ```
> curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/my-index/message/_percolate' -d '{
>     "doc" : {
>         "message" : "A new bonsai tree in the office"
>     }
> }'
> ```
>
> The above request will yield the following response:
>
> ```
> {
>     "took" : 19,
>     "_shards" : {
>         "total" : 5,
>         "successful" : 5,
>         "failed" : 0
>     },
>     "total" : 1,
>     "matches" : [ 
>         {
>           "_index" : "my-index",
>           "_id" : "1"
>         }
>     ]
> }
> ```

Comment: Hmm of course, why didn't think of perculator here? I think this would do, but ideally (direction I was looking for) there would be an even more lightweight solution using the lucene internals to just test simple filters (i.e. exists, missing, geo, range) without touching the indexes at all. I see the perculator creates an in-memory index for the single document to execute the query on (and you need to register the query) - still a little heavy for this. Any suggestions? I'll have a look at the perculator internals.

Comment: well you can always use the Lucene libraries called directly out of Java but it's not going to re-use anything from Elasticsearch - you'll have to set it up separately.

Comment: Yup that was the direction I was looking at. Any starting point perhaps for testing a document / filter? Or do you think this will be overly complex considering the JSON object needs to be mapped to a lucene document first, etc.?